# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() In C# WinForm

Tags: c#

I need to generate a list of my assemblies for a project. I am using this code :

```
 Assembly[] lstAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

which is somehow working but It doesn't show all of my namespaces in solution.
I want To know why it doesn't show all the namespace in my solution

My solution and its projects are like this:

```
> MySolution'TST'              
>|-->BaseWinApp(Project1)           
>|-->ProductWinApp(Project2)          
>|-->SaleWinApp(Project3)         
>|-->TST(Start Up Project)
```

Comment: Are you asking about assemblies or namespaces? I assume you know, that assembly names have (to have) nothing in common with namespaces (contain in them).

Comment: The call to `GetAssemblies()` shows assemblies, not namespaces. Additionally, it only shows **loaded** assemblies, and .NET always loads assemblies "just-in-time", so they won't show until you actually invoke them.

Comment: Thank you @alejandro, It really helps. It only show loaded assemblies or namespace not the namespace not used yet.

Comment: The method returns the currently loaded assemblies.  Assemblies are loaded by the just-in-time compiler.  Just in time, which of course implies that doing this too early does not give you everything you expect.  You can only get an accurate list when your program does everything it is expected to do and you obtain the list just before it ends.  Pretty unlikely to be useful, but you don't explain why you need this to work.  Next best guess is to look in the bin\Release directory of your EXE project.

Answer (score 1):

It returns just directly referenced libraries by default. You need to load recursively if you want to load all of them.

```
            var myrootAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var loadedPath = myrootAssembly.Location;
            var rootPath = loadedPath.Substring(0, loadedPath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            var referencedPaths = Directory.GetFiles(rootPath, "*.dll");
            foreach (var refPath in referencedPaths)
            {
                assemblyList.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(refPath));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you meant to do something like below which would give you the namespace for that assembly

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Select(t => t.Namespace).ToList();
```